How to convert conditional classes from clxs to cva?
I am trying to convert the below code to cva..
{items.map((item, index) => {
          const isActive = item.key === SOMETHING;
          return (
            <div
              key={index}
              className={clsx(
                `cursor-pointer`,
                {
                  "text-white": isActive && variant === "inverted",
                  "text-stone-950": isActive && variant === "default",
                  "text-[#9b9b9b]": !isActive,
                  "hover:text-white": variant === "inverted",
                  "hover:text-stone-950": variant === "default",
                },
              )}
            >...</div>
    });

I am trying this way -
const textContentCva = cva("", {
    variants: {
      variant: {
        inverted: "hover:text-white",
        default: "hover:text-stone-950",
      },
    },
  });

But not sure how to pass the isActive variable.
I can create activeInverted, activeDefault variant but that doesn't seem good.
Could anyone please tell how should I convert it to use cva?

You could use CSS variables in CVA class names.
We can rationalize the conditions:

variant changes the "accent" color.
isActive changes the default inactive text color #9b9b9b to the accent color.

In CVA, you can have a boolean true variant value but not a boolean false. For the false condition, we can use the defaultVariants to apply the appropriate classes.


const classes = cva('cursor-pointer', {
  variants: {
    variant: {
      default: '[--color:theme(colors.stone.950)]',
      inverted: '[--color:theme(colors.white)]',
    },
    isActive: {
      'default': 'text-[#9b9b9b] hover:text-[--color]',
      true: 'text-[--color]',
    },
  },
  defaultVariants: {
    variant: 'default',
    isActive: 'default',
  },
});
  

function CVAVersion({ variant, isActive }) {
  return <div className={classes({ variant, isActive })}>...</div>;
}

function CLSXVersion({ variant, isActive }) {
  return (
    <div
      className={clsx(
        `cursor-pointer`,
        {
          "text-white": isActive && variant === "inverted",
          "text-stone-950": isActive && variant === "default",
          "text-[#9b9b9b]": !isActive,
          "hover:text-white": variant === "inverted",
          "hover:text-stone-950": variant === "default",
        }
      )}
    >...</div>
  );
}


ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('app')).render(
  <React.Fragment>
    <CLSXVersion variant="default"/>
    <CLSXVersion variant="default" isActive/>
    <CVAVersion variant="default"/>
    <CVAVersion variant="default" isActive/>
    <div class="bg-slate-950">
      <CLSXVersion variant="inverted" />
      <CLSXVersion variant="inverted" isActive />
      <CVAVersion variant="inverted" />
      <CVAVersion variant="inverted" isActive />
    </div>
  </React.Fragment>
);
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.3.1/umd/react.production.min.js" integrity="sha512-QVs8Lo43F9lSuBykadDb0oSXDL/BbZ588urWVCRwSIoewQv/Ewg1f84mK3U790bZ0FfhFa1YSQUmIhG+pIRKeg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.3.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js" integrity="sha512-6a1107rTlA4gYpgHAqbwLAtxmWipBdJFcq8y5S/aTge3Bp+VAklABm2LO+Kg51vOWR9JMZq1Ovjl5tpluNpTeQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://www.unpkg.com/clsx@2.1.1/dist/clsx.min.js" integrity="sha384-dEq4EUqxSIwObxCTXRGn1G8uU8Dqce+ragCb5MYDS6s+QHC2gaYQLxHklTJLaked" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.4.3"></script>
<script>window.exports = {};window.require=()=>clsx</script>
<script src="https://www.unpkg.com/class-variance-authority@0.7.0/dist/index.js" integrity="sha384-Ua/NUydOXqPPKWdUxsvNqN7S97GagbtZ08VsSKGzqMYr/WwqcQ6Ajsq1LYfkfOn4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.4.3"></script>

<div id="app"></div>




What I have understand so far is that you are trying to do as below:
const textContentCva = cva("", {
  variants: {
    variant: {
      inverted: "hover:text-white",
      default: "hover:text-stone-950",
    },
    state: {
      active: "",
      inactive: "text-[#9b9b9b]",
    },
  },
  compoundVariants: [
    { variant: "default", state: "active", class: "text-stone-950" },
    { variant: "inverted", state: "active", class: "text-white" },
  ],
});

{items.map((item, index) => {
  const isActive = item.key === SOMETHING;
  return (
    <div
      key={index}
      className={clsx(
        `cursor-pointer`,
        textContentCva({variant: variant, state: isActive ? 'active' : 'inactive' })
      )}
    >...</div>
});

